# Obteniendo datos nulos con LEFT OUTER JOIN entre dos tablas

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    tr_HistoryRecords a
LEFT JOIN tr_HistoryRecords1 b
    ON
    a.id_employee = b.id_employee
WHERE
    b.id_employee IS NULL;
```

[image: Tabla a]
[image: Tabla b]

Quiero pasar datos que no existen en "b" de "a", pero no funciona mi consulta.

PD. Hace días este código funcionaba perfectamente.

Comment: qué es lo que no funciona?

Comment: La consulta se muestra nula, deberia devolver el registro de la tabla a con el id_course 205

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que tu consulta funcione como quieres, tienes que agregar la columna `id_course` como condición del `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tr_HistoryRecords a 
LEFT JOIN tr_HistoryRecords1 b
    ON a.id_employee = b.id_employee 
    AND a.id_course = b.id_course
WHERE b.id_employee IS NULL;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @lamak ahora funciona perfectamente!